# PHP Redirecting to Custom URL if trailing slash is absent or with parameters

Tags: php, redirect

I want to redirect to a custom URL if my visitors use any of the URL such as `index.php?permalink=query` or if trailing slash is missing on the `REQUEST_URI`

I do not understand why this is not working for me. For url parameters, its working fine.

What am I doing wrong with the following code?

```
    $requesturl = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

    if($requesturl == "/index.php?permalink=".$query || substr($requesturl, -1) != '/') {
        $redirect_requesturl = $baseurl."/".$query."/";
        Header( 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently' );
        Header( 'Location: ' . $redirect_requesturl );exit;
    }
```

It is redirecting when a query comes as `index.php?permalink=$query` where as when if URL does not contain trailing slash then its not redirecting.

My .htaccess as follow:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)?/$ index.php?permalink=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

I cannot force all URLs to have trailing slash using .htaccess as some of the important URLs does not contain trailing slash.

### EDIT

Though now using the following in .htaccess works, but it adds trailing slash to css or js or font files such as otf / ttf / woff etc.,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|png|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|css|js|xml|xls|xsl|txt|ico|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|otf|flv|swf)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to redirect to a custom URL if my visitors use any of the URL such as `index.php?permalink=query` or if trailing slash is missing on the `REQUEST_URI`

You can use the following rule to accomplish this :

```
RewriteEngine on

# if the requested uri has querystring
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^permalink=.+$ [OR]
# or the trailing slash is missing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
# redirect the request to /custom_url 
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /custom_url? [L,R]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking time to answer, I was looking for more of PHP solution as .htaccess solution is not much of a help to me because of various query on index.php and rewriting them to URL (more of a wordpress url, such as post, page, etc)